# Mass Payment API Multi Currency not working

Tags: php, paypal, payment, currency

According to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/mass-pay/  "Mass Payments can be made from any PayPal sending country and can be sent to any PayPal receiving country, in PayPal supported currencies." but when I try to send to single reciever from USD to AUD it shows  "The account does not have sufficient funds to do this masspay " 
Is there any configuration required for currency conversion?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to pay more out of the account than it has, which doesn't sound like a currency conversion issue to me...

Comment: No, I have sufficient balance in USD around 1,00,000 USD and I try to transfer 3 USD and 1 Euro in another paypal accounts but still is shows me this error only. But if I transfer 3 USD and 5 USD to another paypal accounts, it shows success status but if currencies are different, it shows the insufficient funds error

Comment: @CGT I am not sure but i think you need to add the currency from the below url 
"https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-currencies".

Comment: paypal said : "When you add a new currency, any future payments you receive in that currency will be credited to that balance. Your primary currency is the default currency for sending and requesting payments."

Answer (score 0):

Currency is supported as a payment currency and a currency balance for in-country PayPal accounts only. Please add money in AUD. After that you will pay in AUD.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mass-pay/integration-guide/currency_codes/